Rename workspace in RedHat 7.9
I am using 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux Workstation release 7.9 (Maipo)'.
I wanted to rename all the workspaces with specific names.
I have tried /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/workpsace-names to change the name of workspace.
This doesn't work.
I have tried /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/workpsace-names to change the name of workspace.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
